# What is the new Router Lifecycle in Angular5?

Tags: angular5

I am new in Angular2/4/5 and before some days ago I started my new project in Angular5 with TypeScript.

I have to track the cycle of routing in my component.

Is it possible to achieve it?

I really appreciate your valuable feedback. Thanks in advance.